# Validate XML without having a specific XSD

Tags: java, xml, validation

I am trying to validate (valid xml file) an xml when creating a `XMLStreamReader` using a `XMLInputFactory`.

I know that there is property that can be set in the factory `javax.xml.stream.isValidating` to allow a specific-implementation validation (in my case of xml). But i am working with **java 6 build 43** (Jboss eap 6.0)  and cannot update so this is not working for me (kwnon issue).

So if anybody know about any API (other than StAX) that could do the same thing that would be great !
Please let me know if something is not clearly explained.

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking.  For starters, validation is always against a schema of some sort (XSD, RELAX, Schematron, etc).  For the difference between ***valid XML*** and ***well-formed XML***, I suggest that you read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).  Thanks.

Comment: You're right Ashes .What i meant is Well-formed xml file. for example when i open a none well formed xml file with firefox it shows an error (example XML Parsing Error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, i used the api SAX to create a parser (independently of a xsd schema) using the provided SAXParserFactory and to parse the file. (more details can be found on pages (23/24) at http://apiacoa.org/publications/teaching/xml/api-xml.pdf)

Also, don't forget to mark/reset your inputstream before/after you parse it with the parser (that will throw an exception if the xml file is not well-formed) so you can keep as it is if the parse does not fail.

Answer (score -2):

you can try for java xml validation API by IBM [validation API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxmlvalidapi/)
 **or**
you can use `javax.xml.validation` [javax.xml.validation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html)

**ex :**

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
...

URL schemaFile = new URL("http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd");
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("web.xml"));
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
try {
  validator.validate(xmlFile);
  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
} catch (SAXException e) {
  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
  System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

**EDITED :**

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        File schemaFile = new File("schema.xsd");

        Schema xsdScheme = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);

        Validator validator = xsdScheme.newValidator();

        Source source = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

        validator.validate(source);
```

one link which i found on SO [xsd validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991091/java-xsd-validation-of-xml-without-namespace)

Comment: He asked *"without having a specific XSD"*, yet you offer an answer with a specific XSD (`http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd`)?