# Java SAX XMLFilter not recognizing final variable initialized by a method

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

Java 8.  Eclipse Luna.  I am having bizarre trouble assigning a final variable accessed by an anonymous method body.

**The Background**

I am validating a namespace-less XML file with my own choice of XSD schema. The file has no `xmlns` declaration, but the schema has a `targetNamespace="mynamespace"` declaration. Obviously, the file will fail validation. To make it pass validation regardless, I give a filter to the validator to force it to pretend the XML file has `xmlns="mynamespace"`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991091/java-xsd-validation-of-xml-without-namespace). See the code below.

**The Problem**

Notice the variable `targetNamespace`. If I initialize it with a string literal namespace, validation passes. If I initialize with a method call that returns the *same value*, validation fails.

**The Code**

```
public static void validate(byte[] xmlFile, byte[] xsdFile)
        throws SAXException, IOException, XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError {

    final String targetNamespace = "mynamespace"; // PASS!
    //final String targetNamespace = getTargetNamespace(xsdFile); // FAIL!

    XMLFilter namespaceFilter = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {
        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
                throws SAXException {
            // Make the validator think the XML file's elements have a namespace
            uri = targetNamespace;

            super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
        }
    };

    Source xmlSource = new SAXSource(namespaceFilter, new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlFile)));
    Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xsdFile));
    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema(xsdSource).newValidator().validate(xmlSource);
}

private static String getTargetNamespace(byte[] xsdFile)
        throws XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError {
    XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xsdFile));
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        int event = reader.next();

        // Get the root element's "targetNamespace" attribute
        if (event == XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT) {
            return reader.getAttributeValue(null, "targetNamespace");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**The Error**

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'childtag'. One of '{"mynamespace":childtag}' is expected.

It gets more bizarre.  Validation passes when the method returns `"mynamespace"` as a string literal.  But validation fails when the method obtains the value of `"mynamespace"` from the XSD file.  I have verified with `String.equals()` that the value passed to `super.startElement` when validation fails is indeed *exactly the same* as when validation passes!

The only difference I can see here is that it passes when the value assigned to the final variable `targetNamespace` is ultimately **a constant** (the string literal), and it fails when the value assigned is ultimately **determined by some condition** (derived from the XSD file). Final or effectively final makes no difference.

Is this a known Java bug?  Or is it my lack of understanding of initialization of variables accessed from anonymous methods?  Does the XSD validation really have anything to do with it?

Comment: I found the problem! It is a Java bug. The JDK developer of the XSD code compared the XML tag "childtag" with the expected XSD "childtag" with a == instead of String.equals() in this method: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SubstitutionGroupHandler.getMatchingElemDecl(QName, XSElementDecl)

Now to report the bug and find a workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it seems JDK 8.25 has a bug in this code:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SubstitutionGroupHandler:

public XSElementDecl getMatchingElemDecl(QName element, XSElementDecl exemplar) {
    if (element.localpart == exemplar.fName &&
        element.uri == exemplar.fTargetNamespace) {
        return exemplar;
    }
    ...
}
```

It compares by `==` (reference comparison) instead of `equals` method (content comparison). While the string literal `"mynamespace"` appears to be the same String object in memory as stored by `exemplar.fTargetNamespace`, the String returned by `reader.getAttributeValue` is clearly a different instance.  That's why `==` returns true for one, false for other.

```
// Pass because same instance in memory
String targetNamespace = "mynamespace";

// Fail because different instance in memory
String targetNamespace = reader.getAttributeValue(null, "targetNamespace");
```

You can't change the JDK code, so a workaround is to call `String.intern()` on the variable, and you have a higher chance of being safe against bugs like `==` comparisons.

```
targetNamespace = targetNamespace.intern();
```